# chrome.contextMenus is not available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop some Chrome extensions, guided by the terrible Google developers guide here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html

But I'm stuck with this error:

> chrome.contextMenus is not available: You do not have permission to access this API.
>
> Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Data v0.1",
    "description": "This extension makes information handling easier...",
    "version": "0.1",

    "icons": { "16": "16x16.png" },

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
            "js": [ "data.js" ],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "16x16.png"
    },

    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ...and somewhere a sad, sad google developer is crying

Comment: Take a closer look at the documentation, the answer is found in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but: this API cannot be called from a content script.

If you add a background script, you'll be able to handle `chrome.contextMenus`